# Big Cartel - Home page Shop Now Button

Tags: css, bigcartel

I was using a header that didn't need the "shop now" button.

I've changed it up but it's a new business and I didn't think to keep the code and location.

I tried to reset it, copy both codes and look for the difference but I can't find anything.

I just need the line of code and confirmation of the location to place it, there's a section with the "shop now" bit in code so I assume it goes in there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please be more specific with upfront information that you provide. For example, provide the location of the file where you found the "Shop Now" button code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.